# async function not waiting for the await to end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux

I'm trying to add an `async/await` in my code to have the app wait for the execution of a function to invoke an other one, but I can't seem to be able to figure out where my code is wrong.

I have an API call in a redux action, this is the action

```
export const editSecondaryCategory = (text) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let obj = {
      text
    };
    axios
      .put(
        `${ROOT_URL}/...`,
        obj
      )
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_NOTE, payload: [...annotations] });
        dispatch(loadAllAnnotations(cid, uuid));
      })
      .catch((error) =>
        dispatch(
          notifSend({
            message: error.message,
            kind: "danger",
            dismissAfter: 2000,
          })
        )
      );
  };
};
```

I want, in my component, to wait after this action is completed to call an other function to update the state. Ideally, it should be something like this (I guess?):

```
async updateCategory() {

    // do the thing I have to wait for
    const propsUpdate = await this.props.editSecondaryCategory(text);

    // if you've done the thing then call the function to update the state
    if (updatedCat) {
      this.updateStateArray();
    }

  }
```

And I'd call `this.updateCategory()` inside my component after the user is done editing the information.
Clearly, this code does not work. I know it's wrong, I just don't know why. Basically I have no clue what to write inside `updateCategory()` to make this work.

Please help lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite editSecondaryCategory function to make it async.

```
  export async function editSecondaryCategory(text){
  return (dispatch) => {
    let obj = {
      text
    };
    axios
      .put(
        `${ROOT_URL}/...`,
        obj
      )
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_NOTE, payload: [...annotations] });
        dispatch(loadAllAnnotations(cid, uuid));
      })
      .catch((error) =>
        dispatch(
          notifSend({
            message: error.message,
            kind: "danger",
            dismissAfter: 2000,
          })
        )
      );
  };
};
```

Currently, your function is not an async function do the above changes and check.

Comment: Not true, it simply needs to return a promise. A function doesn't need to be "async" to return a promise. Your change also doesn't actually cause it to wait on the axios call.